# How to disable a specific option in Jquery Autocomplete combox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I have simple drop down box

```
<select id="fruits">
<option value="apple">Apple</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="banana" disabled="true">Banana</option>
</select>
```

The Banana Option is disabled in the drop down.

When I tried to use Jquery Autocomplete Combo box

```
$( "#fruits" ).combobox();
```

The Autocomplete dropdown works fine, but the option Banana ( which has disabled option set ) is not disabled.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's the combobox in the demo
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

try replacing this line:

```
response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
```

with:

```
response( select.children( "option" ).not(':disabled').map(function() {
```

You could also use the excellent [Chosen select element formatter](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) which combines a search box with a formatted select element.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But it removes the disabled option in autocomplete. whereas in original drop down it will show in disabled state. but that's fine. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, there are ways to display to the user but prevent selection within the autocomplete list, but it's best to keep things as simple as possible, if the user might get annoyed if they can see it but not select it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think it's possible.

Even hiding the element with display:none in css still allows it to show in the autocomplete field. Worse, once its selected there it is actually selected in the underlying select box even though it is 'disabled'.

You're only option might be to remove the element when it is disabled, and add it again if it needs to be enabled.